# How a stack overflow get execute permission in ARMv7R

Tags: assembly, arm, stack-overflow, exploit, armv7

Recently I was researching a vulnerability in HP printer, I noticed there are a similar vulnerability research: https://research.checkpoint.com/2018/sending-fax-back-to-the-dark-ages/.

Because this is my first research on arm architecture, I am curious how to make stack overflow to execute code.

As the text says, Basic ROP that flushes the D-Cache and I-Cache can make the data form stack gain execution. I want to know how to flushes the D-Cache and I-Cache with assembly code, I tried many codes according to the arm manual, but it can not work, did someone know?

Comment: how else would you do it, if not with machine code (assembly language)?

Comment: what part of the arm documentation did you not understand?

Comment: First of all thank you for your reply. Now I also have a stack overflow vulnerability in HP printer, so I need to execute code from stack, but it raise a PREFETCH error, as the article says it can execute by flushes the D-Cache and I-Cache, so I read the manual:http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0363g/DDI0363G_cortex_r4_r1p4_trm.pdf, I tried disable PMU, disable I-Cache and D-Cache("8.5.5 Cache interaction with memory system" in manual), I also try to flush the Cache as the manual   say, but all do not work.